# packaging multiple pre-compiled binary python c extensions(.so, created using SWIG interface)

Tags: python, swig, python-packaging

I have used SWIG to generate wrapper code for my c application and compiled them as shared libraries (dynamically linked). Now I want to package my application be able to install it on another device. 
I have a single module called the shiftedkey.c with a function shiftedkey1() which is dependent on other modules gn.c and noise.c. Wrapper code for all of these modules have been generated. 
My directory structure

```
maincode
|
|__shiftedkey.py
|__shiftedkey.pyc
|__shiftedkey_wrap.c
|__shiftedkey.c
|__ _shiftedkey.so
|
|__gn.py
|__gn.pyc
|__gn_wrap.c
|__gn.c
|__ _gn.so
|
|__noise.py
|__noise.pyc
|__noise_wrap.c
|__noise.c
|__ _noise.so
|
|__setup.py
|__ __iniy__.py
```

and my setup.py is:

```
setup(
name = 'sift',
version = '0.1',
description = 'A Python wrapper for a top secret algorithm',
url = None,
author = 'Bond',
author_email = 'James.Bond.007@mi6.org',
license = 'Spy Game License',
zip_safe = True,
py_modules = ['shiftedkey'],
package_data = {'sift': ['_shiftedkey.so']}
)
```

1. is the package structure correct?
2. Where do i add my module dependency(noise,and gn modules).
3. where do i add the pre-compiled binary extensions. as it is not being detected in  package_data.

kindly help.

Got this sorted, compiled shiftedkey.c,gn.c,noise.c into a single module as individual functions .package structure being :

```
maincode
 |__maincode
     |_ ___init__.py
     |_<maincode.c>
     |_ <maincode.i>
     |_ <maincode.h>
 |__MANIFEST
 |__SETUP.PY
 |__lib
```

the setup.py file is :

```
 from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extensions
 maincode = Extension('_maincode',
             sources=['maincode/maincode_wrap.c',
                      'maincode/maincode.c'],
             depends=['maincode/maincode.h'])

 setup(  name="maincode",
 py_modules=['maincode'],
 packages=['maincode'],
 include_package_data=True,
 package_data={'maincode':['lib/*.dat','maincode/_maincode.so']},
 ext_modules=[maincode]
 ,)
```

Add manifest file for your package data (.dat files in my case.)
MANIFEST FILE:
     `include lib/*.dat`

Comment: Got this sorted,  compiled siftedkey.c, noise.c, gn.c functions into a single .c file (or module), package structure thus being :